# Proof verification that $\sup_{||x||=1} |\langle Tx, x \rangle | = ||T||$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I have been trying to solve the following exercise:

> Suppose that for an operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $\left\||Tx_n - \lambda x_n \right\| \to 0$ with $||x_n|| = 1$ so that $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $T$. If $|\lambda| = ||T||$ show that $\sup_{||x||=1} |\langle Tx, x \rangle | = ||T||$.

Could you please verify my proof?

The first direction is easy as for a unit vector $x$

$$|\langle Tx, x \rangle | \leq \left\|Tx\right\| \left\|x\right\| \leq \left\| T \right\| \left\|  x\right\|^2$$

so  $\sup_{||x||=1} |\langle Tx, x \rangle | \leq ||T|| $.

For the other direction I was thinking I could again use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to get

$$\left| \langle T x_n - \lambda x_n, x_n \rangle  \right| =  \left| \langle T x_n,x_n \rangle - \lambda  \right|< \epsilon$$

for large enough $n$. Hence by the reverse triangle inequality

$$|\lambda| < \left| \langle T x_n,x_n \rangle  \right| + \epsilon \leq \sup_{||x||=1} |\langle Tx, x \rangle | + \epsilon $$

so $ |\lambda| = ||T|| \leq \sup_{||x||=1} |\langle Tx, x \rangle | $ and assuming this is correct, the proof is complete.

Is everything alright in the above?

Thank you.

Comment: Everything looks alright

Comment: @Aweygan Great, thanks.